# Pheanstalk reserve function

Tags: php, beanstalkd, pheanstalk

I have just started using pheanstalk and am having an issue with the reserve function. I have the following code for a worker script:

```
<?php
  //... code that requires the autoload.php page among and other

  $queue = new Pheanstalk_Pheanstalk("127.0.0.1:11300");
  $queue->watch("action_tube");
  $job = $queue->reserve();

  //... code that would then output the information obtained from the job
?>
```

The issue I am having is that the code always gets stuck when preforming the reserve function. I know for a fact that it is getting stuck there because I went through the effort of running this code in a browser and using `echo` while commenting out code to see exactly where the code is getting stuck. It's as if an infinit while loop is happening inside the reserve function.

For instance, if I were to comment out `$job = $queue->reserve()`, the code would low freely and the page would immediately load, however if I don't comment it out, the circle loading in the browser keeps on going forever.

**QUESTION:** Why might I be having this problem? Is this normal for the reserve function? Does it just stand waiting for something to appear in the queue? I do actually have the `"action_tube"` queue created from a previous script so I would think that the `reserve` function would take some of these out. Might the condition of the queue cause a reserve function to stall? Any feedback is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Beanstalk reserve will run forever until the job is ready

> `reserve` blocks until a job is ready, possibly forever. If that is not desired, we can invoke reserve with a timeout (in seconds) how long we want to wait to receive a job. If such a reserve times out, it will return `None`:

```
>>> beanstalk.reserve(timeout=0) is None
True
```

Found this [here](http://beanstalkc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html)

Comment: Oh so it is supposed to be a forever loop until it finds something in the queue?